# Writing a doubling equation given only amount of time to double.

Tags: exponential-function

Write an equation to model the generation of Ecoli if the doubling time is 20 minutes.

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the initial population. Then the population at time $t$(measured in minutes) can be calculated
$$ p(t) = r 2^{t/20} $$